# 'LDF' is not a valid database file header. The PageAudit property is incorrect

Tags: sql-server-2008, import

I 'am trying to import database into sqlserver 2008 using this query

```
EXEC sp_attach_db @dbname = 'LIQ_DEV_V9',  
@filename1='/home/elsayedawd/DATA/databasedumbs/database9/LIQ_DEV_V9.mdf',  
@filename2='/home/elsayedawd/DATA/databasedumbs/database9/LIQ_DEV_V9_log.LDF';
```

but it failed with

> Error: The header for file
>   '/home/elsayedawd/DATA/data-base-dumbs/database-9/LIQ_DEV_V9_log.LDF'
>   is not a valid database file header. The PageAudit property is
>   incorrect. SQLState:  S00015 ErrorCode: 5172

Comment: ,There could be two possibility the log file or data file is damaged or you are attching a higer version database to a lower version server.

Comment: Ok , is it possible to import without log file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Ok , is it possible to import without log file?

Yes, but stop using [deprecated procedures like `sp_attach_db`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-attach-db-transact-sql) (see the big warning at the top).

Next, you need to supply paths to SQL Server that make sense. Can you get to `/home/` in Windows Explorer? Can you do that when logged in as the SQL Server service account?

```
CREATE DATABASE LIQ_DEV_V9
  ON 
  (
    name = LIQ_DEV_V9, 
    filename = 'C:\...\LIQ_DEV_V9.mdf'
  )
  FOR ATTACH_REBUILD_LOG;
```

*This might fail if SQL Server attempts to create a new log file in a location where that file already exists; so if the damaged LDF file is in that same folder, you may want to rename it, move it, or delete it.*

**More importantly**, you really shouldn't be relying on mdf/ldf files as backups; please read this post:

- [Bad Habits : Using MDF/LDF Files as "Backups"](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-file-backups)